# Use su in shell script

Tags: macos, bash, shell

How would I do the following in a shell script?

```
$ su my_user
Password: my_password
```

This is required, as I need to install `homebrew` on a mac, and it won't allow me to install it under `sudo`, but requires that I have admin privileges.

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(/usr/bin/curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/master/Library/Contributions/install_homebrew.rb)"
Password:
Don't run this as root!
```

And why I can't run this as a current user (who is not an admin) -

```
$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(/usr/bin/curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/master/Library/Contributions/install_homebrew.rb)"
This script requires the user to be an Administrator. If this
sucks for you then you can install Homebrew in your home directory or however
you please; please refer to our homepage. If you still want to use this script
set your user to be an Administrator in System Preferences or `su' to a
non-root user with Administrator privileges.
```

It is not an option to be logged in as an admin to run the script, I must `su` in the script.

Comment: running the script with root privileges is no option?

Comment: sudo doesn't just do root.  `sudo -u username` lets you run something as a different, non-root user

Comment: The real question, then, looks like it is *not* "How do I run su in a shell script?", but "how do I install Homebrew on a Mac, given that it won't run either as myself or sudo'd to root?" -- which is an entirely different question.

Comment: @user1383058 If it intentionally won't let you run it sudo'd to root, why do you think it would let you run it su'd? The point is to use a non-root administrative user, which the text of the error makes quite clear.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy because when I try it works

Comment: @user1383058 That's a bug, then -- the point of the restriction on sudo is what the text describes, a non-root Administrator (that is, a member of the wheel group); using su instead of sudo simply subverts that goal.

Answer (score 2):

On a mac, there is a difference between `root` and an administrator. Administrator roughly translates to the `wheel` group on a standard Unix/Linux system, meaning those in the "administrators" group can gain elevated privileges using their password (à la sudo). Make sure the user under which you're trying to run this is an administrator: click on the apple menu in the upper left-hand corner, System Preferences, Users & Groups. It should say "Admin" under your name; if it doesn't, that's your problem. Click on the lock (bottom left of the window), put in the username and password of an administrator account on the machine, click on your user, then check the "Allow user to administer this computer" box.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to do it from a outside  a shell, like bash or ssh or telnet , managed by 'expect'
try

```
man expect
```

or for a short introduction
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect